# Hesitation about blank fields in access database

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to get some values from a DB in *.accdb format from Microsoft Access. I'm writing a Java programa that using the proper jdbc driver gets values from the Access database.

The query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

I am able to retrieve all values that I need and I have no problem with that. The issue comes when I see that some (apparently, but I'm quite sure they are) empty fields on the file, are retrieved as "null" or "" (empty strings) for TEXT datatype columns when I convert the results to strings in Java.

I analyzed the database looking for the default value of each column etc.. but I found no logical reason for retrieving null or "" for an empty cell. According to office support page:

> When a field contains no values, it contains a Null value or, **for Text, Memo, or Hyperlink fields, a Null value or a zero-length string**.

Then I see that empty fields can be returned in both types but I still can't understand **the criteria**.

Comment: In generall I would write each column in my SELECT and in MSSQL Servers you get an "" (empty string) from column 1 and `Null` from column 2 if the db entry was written with e.g. `Insert Into 'table' (1) Values ( "")`

Comment: So I guess that when I get a null or en empty string from a blank field , is because it depends how the person entered the value?

Comment: Not quite...
That depends on how the software writing to the DB is designed. If it checks whether the value is "" and doesn't change the `Null` to "" you will get `Null` instead.

Comment: Ok so your answer would be that depending how the software WRITING to the DB works and depending how it treats and writes empty values, then one type or another will be returned. Could be?

Comment: Yes...I write a Post on how you can simulate that. (Worked for me in MSSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that in MSSQL databases it depends on how the value is entered.

If you have a table like this (asuming als cols are String):

```
tbl1
----------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
```

Now you insert data in like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1)
VALUES ('Test')
```

You are likely to get:

```
col1: Test
col2: Null
Col3: Null
```

But if yoy insert data like that (e.g. you don't check if the value is "" in col2)

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('Test', '', '')
```

you will get:

```
col1: Test
col2: ""
Col3: ""
```

This happens mostly by not only inserting data filled by the user instead of the whole data.

Comment: Ok I'll write it as correct answer as soon as I get one little answer from office support. If this is correct I'll mark it correct 'cause you deserve it!

Comment: Feel free to correct me if office support states something else. Thanks

Comment: Well done, I added the explanation but technically (talking in query terms) it was pretty much what you stated. Congrats.